# Branch Out - Monkey Edition

Tags: code-golf, recursion, algorithm, tree-traversal

#### The Monkey has swung home to find his tree all in pieces.

He likes order and scoops up all his 'tree-parts' and sets them out in `3` groups.

The Monkey's `3` nested lists:

```
STEP = [['S', '1', 'B', '3'], ['S', '3', 'B', '11'], ['S', '5', 'B', '12'], ['S', '4', 'B', '13'], ['S', '2', 'B', '14']]

TRANSITION = [['T', '2', 'B', '4'], ['T', '7', 'B', '4'], ['T', '3', 'S', '4'], ['T', '5', 'S', '5'], ['T', '1', 'S', '2'], ['T', '8', 'S', '2'], ['T', '6', 'S', '1'], ['T', '9', 'S', '2'], ['T', '4', 'S', '1'], ['T', '10', 'S', '1']]

BRANCH = [['B', '3', 'T', '1'], ['B', '3', 'T', '7'], ['B', '4', 'S', '3'], ['B', '11', 'T', '3'], ['B', '11', 'T', '5'], ['B', '12', 'T', '6'], ['B', '12', 'T', '8'], ['B', '13', 'T', '4'], ['B', '13', 'T', '9'], ['B', '14', 'T', '2'], ['B', '14', 'T', '10']]
```

Each element holds information as such:

```
# Example

STEP[0]  =  ['S', '1', 'B', '3']
```

*Where:*

- 'S' is the `STEP` type
- '1' is the `STEP` number id
- 'B' is the linked `BRANCH` type
- '3' is the linked `BRANCH` number id

Starting from a `STEP` the data is all linked, so using the linked reference you can find the next element and the next until another `STEP` is reached.

*This is some parameters of the data:*

- `STEPS` are connected to single `BRANCHES`
- `BRANCHES` are connected to one or more `TRANSITIONS`
- `TRANSITIONS` can be connected to a single `BRANCH` or `STEP`

The `BRANCH` data can have a fork where a single `BRANCH` id has one or more options for `TRANSITIONS`.

Re-create this monkey's tree (nested list format is fine) in the shortest way possible (he is not a fan of long instructions):

```
           [S1]
            |          
          B3|_________ 
            |         |
           [T1]     [T7]
            |         |
            |       B4|
            |         |
           [S2]     [S3]
```

And list all the routes on this tree:

```
Routes = [[S1, B3, T1, S2], [S1, B3, T7, B4, S3]]
```

UPDATE: This is Code-golf and from the data given you need to output the display of the tree ( This can be different from my example but requires the same elements to be displayed in any format) and as you cycle through the problem to output all the possible routes as a BONUS.

#### Notes:

- This is a single-rooted tree
- You may use a different format for input but please explicitly state the input format in your solution

Comment: Pretty new here, still getting the etiquette down. Yes Code-golf and from the data given you need to output the display of the tree ( This can be different from my example but requires the same elements to be displayed in any format) and as you cycle through the problem to output all the possible routes as a BONUS.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! What are acceptable outputs for the tree? Can it just be nested lists? Or does it need to be some [`ascii-art`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/ascii-art/info)? (in which case this tag should be added and the format should be specified some more)

Comment: @arnauld - thank you! It can just be nested lists - okay, fantastic Ill update that

Comment: Welcome to CCPG! I enjoy graph theory related challenges. Some questions: 1. The input seems a bit laborious; can we simply take a single list of tuples `(x,y)` where `x` and `y` are strings? E.g.: `[('S1', 'B3'), ('B3', 'T1'), ('B3, 'T7'), ...]`? 2. Can we assume that the graph described by the input is a single rooted tree?

Comment: Hi @ChasBrown -- Yes that will be fine, I thought that keeping them separated makes it easier to crunch when numbers are larger than 9 - but feel free to modify the input format -- as long as it can reproduce the tree and the input is explicitly stated in your solution - yes this is a single-rooted tree. Thank you for the feedback - I'll take it on board for future posts!

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 570 bytes

```java
t->{return "Routes = "+Arrays.deepToString(Arrays.stream(r(t.get(0).get(0),t,t.get(0).get(0)).split("\\[")).filter(d->d.endsWith("]")).map(d->d.replaceAll("]", "")).map(d->d.split("(?=[A-Z])")).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray());};String r(String s, List<List<String>>t, String b){List<String>o = t.stream().filter(e->e.get(0).equals(s)).map(e->e.get(1)).collect(Collectors.toList());if(s.matches("^S(?!(?:1)$)\\d+"))return s;if(o.size()>1){String x="";for(String n:o){x+="["+b+r(n,t,b+n)+"]";}return x;}if(o.size()==1)return s+r(o.get(0),t,b+o.get(0));return "]";}
```

As you may notice by my code I´m still learning a lot every day.
My answer is neighter pretty nor short and I honestly even hope this works for different testcases even though I tested a couple.
But I hope that this question gets the attention it deserves and there will be more answers I can learn from.

### INPUT

```java
String[][] STEP = { { "S1", "B3" },  ... ,{ "B14", "T2" }, { "B14", "T10" } };
List<List<String>> tupels = Arrays.stream(STEP).map(Arrays::asList).collect(Collectors.toList());
z(tupels);
```

I converted your given Input into an 2D-Java-Array `String[][]` and converted that into a `List<List<String>>`.

### CODE

The first method calls a recursive method to get all routes and formats the output.

```java
t->{
return "Routes ="+Arrays.deepToString(
  Arrays.stream(r(t.get(0).get(0),t,t.get(0).get(0)).split("\\["))
 .filter(d->d.endsWith("]")).map(d->d.replaceAll("]", ""))
 .map(d->d.split("(?=[A-Z])")).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray());
};
```

The second method is the recursive method which gathers all the possible routes

```java
String r(String s, List<List<String>>t, String b){
  List<String>o =t.stream().filter(e->e.get(0).equals(s)).map(e->e.get(1))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
  if(s.matches("^S(?!(?:1)$)\\d+"))
    return s;
  if(o.size()>1){
    String x="";
    for(String n:o){
      x+="["+b+r(n,t,b+n)+"]";
    }
    return x;
  }
  if(o.size()==1)
    return s+r(o.get(0),t,b+o.get(0));
  return "]";
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVRtT9swEP7eX@FZ@2AvaUSgDGiWIpj4tqFpjTRpbSeliQtmbpzZLoNV@e2dX/JSAohWSvI857t77mzfXXqfDu/y3zu6LrlQ4E7jYKMoCz5Eg2ecVIKka2MaZCyVEnxNabEdAEALRcQqzQi4NhCAqRK0uAEZ@kKl@mQfjppMgMKRXlMN9OMaFCDeqeFkK4jaiALA73yjiAQxgN6FEOmjDHJCyoQ7b1RzTggSSAU3RKEDXL985fcYHMiSUYXgfD6DGq0o01JRPpzkASly@YOqWwQXxrROS8cLUjJdywVjxuID@MRax0Pn8exi@HOBjTHjjJFMoc/uzYUMFDdVI21U3KrWn1EV1Y0RqP6QPnjeIuU3DVzi7b6F68aopvq2GDKckKZq8meTMolkrbg1hW@ojOgKSe2islsiEfw1Refv0Pk4xO/xfJ57ush6h6RZyQNJ/xGEJyHe1kofYgijFW8LK8Ycbx@8GM6gt/QEKvTeLL0Ce7qlUVUHe4iqvWhxHLZZtAfvNnXpNQBHzUkxYXYAlJsloxmQKlX6dc9pDtb6VNYyZguQihuJ90/lbKHZaXL1TTdzq/9wGppNvjyCoPItPrI4DFvi2BGHLTFyROdy6IiRIWyu/Z9ekLgFo8YhOelhm3PaYZtSJ26w1ThtFSSnHX4x30drb0tIznr@o549PHhKXFpBSR@fvJbw0gVsO2La59u6esRxR9ieaKU94rQjXNJXu9osOOs8rIzksE/o8kAFqmhgw7w0lTYlYWbwPB0x5py4q@T48TiVxvGN2@SO26NUZB3oiRaUOotiBSrIXzs09eUtggy5pLgeiNXuPw)